# Pushforward through $\pi : \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ of vector field given by homogeneous polynomials.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-space

Let $\pi:\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\smallsetminus 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ be the canonical projection, let $\mathcal{O}(1)$ be the hyperplane bundle over $\mathbb{P}^n$ and let $(x_0,\dots,x_n)$ be the canonical coordinates on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. For $n\geq 0$ denote $\mathcal{O}(n)=\mathcal{O}(1)^{\otimes(n)}$

Suppose $V=\sum_{i=0}^n P_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is a vector field on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ where each $P_i$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $x_0,\dots, x_n$ of degree $r$. Then, in why can $$\pi_*(V)=\sum_{i=0}^n P_i \pi_\star \big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\big)$$ be interpreted as a global section of the bundle $ \mathcal{O}(r-1) \otimes T \mathbb{P}^n$? Or (equivalently, I hope), why is $\pi_*(V)$ the product of a homogeneous polynomial of degree $r-1$ with a global vector field on $\mathbb{P}^n$?

The reason for this question is that I'm trying to understand the following extract:

> Let $\Theta_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ be the tangent and hyperplanes sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^n$. For an $\mathcal{O} _{\mathbb{P}^n}$-sheave $\mathcal E$ let $\mathcal E(d) = \mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{H}^{\otimes d}$ if $d\geq 0$ and and $\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal (\mathcal{H} ^*)^{-d}$ if $d\leq 0$. Let $\Pi:\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\smallsetminus 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ be the natural projection. The twisted Euler sequence is then
>
> $$ 0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n} (r-1) \stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(r)^{\oplus (n+1)} \stackrel{\Pi_*}{\longrightarrow} \Theta_{\mathbb{P}^n} (r-1) \rightarrow 0 . $$

But the codomain for $\Pi_*$ doesn't make sense to me.

I'm very new to this topic and have been stumbling hard, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you start by understanding the usual Euler sequence $$0\to \mathscr O \to\mathscr O(1)^{\oplus (n+1)} \to \mathscr \Theta_{\Bbb P^n}\to 0?$$ Then you just tensor with $\mathscr O(r-1)$. (You can find the Euler sequence discussed on here numerous places. I know I've written a few answers on it.)

Comment: @TedShifrin I do think I understand that sequence. I also understand that tensoring with $\mathcal{O}(r-1)$ is an exact functor and this gives exactness of the sequence in my question. The problem is, after tensoring, the map $\Pi_*$ stops making sense to me. If it is simply the pushforward as written in my question, then it doesn't seem to have $\Theta_{\mathbb{P}^n}(r-1)$ as codomain.

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess a new question I didn't realize I had is: is $\Pi_*$ defined as I did on my question, the same map as the map you get when you tensorize the usual Euler sequence by $\mathcal{O}(r-1)$? i.e. the map $$\mathcal{O}(1)^{n+1}\otimes \mathcal{O}(r-1)\rightarrow \Theta_{\mathbb{P}^n} \otimes \mathcal{O}(r-1)$$ given by $$X\otimes h \mapsto \pi_*(X)\otimes h.$$

Comment: Yes, I believe that’s all that’s going on.

Comment: @TedShifrin That those maps are equal?

Comment: Yes, you have homogeneous polynomials as coefficients of the vectors that push forward.